# can't run sass after successfully installing it

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass

I did `sudo gem install sass`, which succeeded. Running `sudo sass -v` works fine, but running as a normal user gives:

```
$ sass -v
-bash: /usr/bin/sass: Permission denied
```

Indeed the executable's permissions are 700. I changed the permissions to 755, but that leads to:

```
$ sass -v
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'sass' (>= 0) among 4 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/sass:22:in `<main>'
```

I've google'd for everything but can't find a solution to this. Here's the output of `gem env`, which is identical if I do `sudo gem env`.

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-13
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/ashish/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

I had to use sudo to install. Otherwise, I get:

```
$ gem install sass
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

Comment: Don’t use `sudo`; just `gem install sass`.

Comment: I added explanation of why I had to install with sudo.

Comment: what about other gems , can you run any other gems ? ANd obviously you ran the command with `sudo` privileges, you can't access it without sudo. Either you have change the permission or have to move the files.

Comment: In my experience, installing gems requires sudo, but running them doesn't.  You might have better luck asking on SuperUser or expanding your tags to encompass unix commands.

Comment: I believe the main issue is how are gems supposed to be installed on Mac, which has ruby pre-installed. I don't use Ruby, so this is the first gem I've tried to use. Maybe I'm supposed to configure the installation to go into my own home directory, and thus not use sudo? Also, I use homebrew. I tried with and without `brew install ruby`, but I got the same errors.

Comment: The error you receive when you try to install sass without sudo is that you `don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.`

Have you tried using sudo/root to give your normal user permissions to write to that directory? I would recommend doing this and then running `gem install sass` as your normal user again.

Comment: Thanks, I can try that. However, it feels wrong. I shouldn't have to muck around with sudo settings. I should either be able to install within my home directory and avoid sudo altogether, or I should be able to do a system install by calling sudo before every command.

Comment: I'm now using `node-sass`, which can be installed easily with NPM.

Answer (score 5):

It worked for me:
- First I´ve installed Homewbrew with:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

(DO NOT use sudo for this step!!)

- verify the install with :

  brew -v
- verify your Ruby install with :

  ruby -v
- install sass with

  gem install sass
- verify gem with:

  sass --version

and finally do:

```
rvm list known
```

Now I have:
laomusics-mbp% ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin10.0]
in a OSX 1068, MBP.

Hope this helps others !

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and also kept looking around for a long time. Eventually I had to uninstall Ruby and re-install it, only this time I did so with Homebrew, which is a package manager for Mac that gets it right.

Steps:

- Make a list of the gems that are installed in your system and that you'll want to get back by writing `gem list` (most of them will get installed with the re-installation of the framework)
- Completely uninstall Ruby: have a look at the following post https://superuser.com/questions/194051/how-to-completely-remove-ruby-ruby-gems-on-mac-os-x-10-6-4
- Install Homebrew if you don't have it installed: http://brew.sh/
- run `brew install ruby`

Now it should all be fine. Test it by installing a gem, for example `sudo gem install sass`, and once done, checking whether it's working with `sass --version`

Hope this helped you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try this next time I need it.