# Sublime Text 3 Sass Building Error

Tags: ruby, sass, sublimetext3

I am trying to build a SASS file for HTML, but when I go to build I get the following error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:250:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem sass (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:278:in `activate_bin_path'
from /usr/local/bin/sass:22:in `<main>'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['sass', '--update', '/Users/Dexstrum/Desktop/template/style.scss:/Users/Dexstrum/Desktop/template/style.css', '--stop-on-error', '--no-cache']]
[dir: /Users/Dexstrum/Desktop/template]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

I have Ruby, RVM, and SASS installed

```
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]
rvm 1.29.1 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io/]
Sass 3.4.23 (Selective Steve)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is something has been installed in the wrong place and it can't be found. Uninstall and reinstall sass first.

Open Terminal, and type:

```
sudo gem uninstall sass
```

Then type:

```
sudo gem install sass
```

If that doesn't fix it, you may need to uninstall ruby, rvm and sass, then reinstall. You're likely to have more luck reinstalling these using Homebrew. See Laoumusicarts answer here for more details:

[can't run sass after successfully installing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121622/cant-run-sass-after-successfully-installing-it)